# Button Group with more icons LDS

Tags: lightning-design-system, button, lightning-buttonicon

I'm trying to add Button Group with more icons in to my LDS VF page. Here's what I'm trying. (directly copied from the documentation)

```
<div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">New Work</button>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Edit</button>                                    
    <apex:commandButton action="{!HomePage}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" value="Home"/>                                
    <div class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-button--last">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled" aria-haspopup="true" title="Show More">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SDLS203,'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down')}"></use>
            </svg>                                                                                      
        </button>
        <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--right">
            <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">
                <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Test Button</button> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work as expected. When the drop down icon is clicked it doesn't display rest of the buttons under UL, but it will refreshes the page. Please help to figure this out

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: My bad. When the drop down icon is clicked it doesn't display rest of the buttons under UL, but it will refreshes the page

Comment: Any thoughts???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu does not just appear on its own.

You need to use JS to add/remove the class .slds-is-open to the wrapper for the onclick event.

Add an Id to the dropdown div and then you can do

```
$('#DIVID']).toggleClass('slds-is-open');
```

assuming you are using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

For this section in your code:

```
<div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--right">
    <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">
        <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Test Button</button> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add the attribute `type="button"` for the button used. It helps preventing the page to be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks, according to your explanation this particular attribute should be added to the button that holds the svg (down icon) icon right? So I added that and it helped not refresh the page. But it still doesn't load rest of the button